# Soap Client Method parameter array omits keys - PHP

Tags: php, yii, soap-client

I'm trying to use the default SOAP Client of XAMPP PHP, i need to pass array as parameter to SoapClient method invocation, but the methos receives parameter without array keys,

MyCode:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/crm/WSIn07/ws'); 
$data = array("name"=>"xxx","age"=>"32");
echo $client->UpdateEmp($data);
```

but in controller method the array  prints as ["xxx","32"]
so when i try to access $data["name"] it throws **undefined index error : name**

Please anyone provide me an idea to send array with keys to SOAPClient method

Comment: Please provide the wsdl specification about the method UpdateEmp, what the server is expecting?

Comment: Your wsdl must have the correct structure to receive params as array: https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_types  "Array types should extend the Array type defined in the SOAP v1.1 encoding schema (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/)"

Answer (score 0):

This string looks like a json, so you can use **json_decode()** function to convert this data *(In your controller inside the function UpdateEmp)*.

Use **isset()** and prevents undefined index error.

*Try something like this:*

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/crm/WSIn07/ws'); 
$data = array("name"=>"xxx","age"=>"32");

$decoded = json_decode($client->UpdateEmp($data));

if (isset($decoded["name"])) {
echo $decoded["name"];
}

if (isset($decoded["age"])) {
echo $decoded["age"];
}
```

Comment: my question is inside UpdateEmp method  key is not defined